# How are single photons correlated inside the "coherence time" of the laser? (And how would this affect a random number generator?)

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, stochastic-processes, randomness

[This review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03304) on quantum random number generation describes how random numbers can be generated from a simple optical setup. In one example setup they give: weak light travels through a beam splitter and each path is sent into two detectors, we can label measurements of one detector as a 1 and the other detector as 0.

But in it they describe that the coherence time of the light source is an important factor, something which I don't understand. In the article they write:

> Another important point is the choice of photon sources. In many of
> the reviewed generators, the photons come from LEDs. In order to
> guarantee independent photons, the rate is limited to be much smaller
> than the coherence time, which is usually not a problem as the
> limiting factor tends to the be the dead time of the detectors. A
> common alternative is using weak laser light.

I am having trouble following this. First off, if two photons are produced within the same coherence time of the laser/LED, why is this a problem for our random number generator? They suggest that this would imply that these photons would be correlated, but I don't see how. I would have thought that each photon will travel its own random path upon hitting the beamsplitter and the same type of randomness is expected.